# Angular ng-option index issue

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am stuggling with ng-options in Angular version 1. The issue is a follows:

I have a json file that I read to populate a drop-down select:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'collection_countries.json'})
        .then(function successCallback(response) {            
            $scope.collection_countries = response.data;
            $scope.collection_country=$scope.collection_countries[0]; // pre-seelct       
        }
 );
```

I then generate the drop down as follows:

```
<select class="form-control" name="deliver_to" ng-model="destination_country" ng-options="item as item.country for item in countries track by item.id" required>
     <option value="" disdabled>Select Country</option>
</select>
```

This works ok to this point, however I am trying read the selected value and corresponding data form the json as follows:

```
$scope.countries[ $scope.destination_country['country']['id'] ];
```

As you can see the value $scope.destination_country['country']['id'] is the id which is arbitrary and does not correspond with the index of the json object.

As I see it I have two options:

1. In the ng-options directive I track by $index (or similar as I know $index is for ng-repeat and not ng-options)
2. Some how reference the json object by the country_id

I created this plunkr to demonstrate the issue.

https://plnkr.co/edit/19H8A12VnVpdlHQe5vM7?p=preview

Thanks.

Comment: The ng-options you posted doesn't match with the JS code you posted. But even more important: what are you trying to achieve? The selected country is stored in collection_country. It's one of the elements of collection_countries. What else do you need?

Comment: @JBNizet I was totally over thinking this - the aim was to set a second drop down with the same value. See my updated plunkr now, I have left an example of what I was trying to do and how I achieved it: https://plnkr.co/edit/19H8A12VnVpdlHQe5vM7?p=preview

Comment: Again, I don't understand what you want to achieve. What's the point of having two select boxes with the same options, and the same selected value?